# Number of Binary Search Tree with height 4

Tags: combinatorics, trees

**How many Binary Search trees have 6 nodes with a depth of 4?**

If I try to create them manually one by one, then there is a chance that I may miss some of the Binary Search trees, please suggest some approach to solve this kind of questions.

PS: I know that with $n$ distinct numbers, total possible Binary Search Trees are $$\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}.$$

[edit]
I am getting only 8 Binary Search Trees as shown in the following picture :
[8 possible Binary Search trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcqdM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Having a height of 4 means that 5 of the nodes form a line, the "trunk". The only remaining variation is where the remaining node connects to the trunk. It cannot connect to the lowest trunk node, because that would increase the tree height to 5. So there are exactly 4 choices where it could connect:

$\begin{align}&\bullet - \bullet - \bullet - \bullet - \bullet \\&|\\&\bullet\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\bullet - &\bullet - \bullet - \bullet - \bullet \\&|\\&\bullet\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\bullet - \bullet - &\bullet - \bullet - \bullet \\&|\\&\bullet\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\bullet - \bullet - \bullet - &\bullet - \bullet \\&|\\&\bullet\end{align}$

Now multiply that by the $6!$ ways to assign $1$ thru $6$ to the 6 nodes.

**Edit**

The above wrongly considers unordered trees, but "Binary Trees" are ordered. There are two ways to assign the final node to each of the trunk nodes (except the last to which it cannot be attached). Thus there are 8 possible unlabeled trees.

Also the problem statement was changed after I posted. The original statement was about labeled trees. Thus the comment about at the end about assigning labels no longer applies.

Comment: I think we can't not multiply with 6! for example if I insert keys in this order 
2, 4, 3, 1, 5, and 6. the height of constructed tree is 3 but not 4.
Secondly, your tree is growing towards right side only, i may have a left-skewed Binary Search tree also, isn't it?

Comment: I am only getting 8 Binary Search trees as shown on the following link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcqdM.jpg

Can you please point my mistake if i am making any.

Comment: You have *significantly* changed your problem statement since I posted this. Your original post that I answered asked about how many Binary Trees exist *with nodes labeled 1 to 6*. No requirements were given about how the labels were to be assigned, so any rearrangement of the labels would represent a different tree to be counted (as the nodes are distinguishable, there is not need to worry about two rearrangements giving the same labeled tree), Since you've dropped the labeling requirement (without having bothered to mention it) of course, the part about rearrangement no longer applies.

Comment: And the assigning I was talking about have absolutely nothing do with "inserting keys". Inserting keys is an implementation artifact and has nothing to with the tree structure itself. You take one of the 4 different tree structures given, and for each node in it, choose a label from 1 to 6 to assign it. How you get that into some program has nothing to do with counting how many trees exist. For each tree there are 6! ways to assign unique labels to its nodes.

Comment: However, I will grant that you are right about left vs right. I was thinking of an unordered tree, where there is no such thing as a "left branch" and a "right branch". There are just 2 child branches. However, a check against wikipedia shows that the name "Binary Tree" specifies the tree should be ordered, so in this I was mistaken. With that change, there are two possible ways to attach the final node to each of the 4 trunk nodes it can be added to. Thus there are 8 possible trees, not 4.